# How to use putExtra for input type phone number in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm new in Kotlin by the way.
How to use putExtra for input type phone number in Kotlin. The result that i want is when I click the button, the phone number that I input before can displayed in the second activity.
This is my first activity code

```
package com.example.praktikumppb

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class Pendaftaran : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val KEY_NAME = "NAMA"
    private val KEY_RM = "RM"
    private val KEY_ALAMAT = "ALAMAT"
    private val KEY_HP = "HP"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pendaftaran)

    val noRM = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumber2)
    val nama = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
    val alamat = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName3)
    val noHp = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextPhone)


    val daftar = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    daftar.setOnClickListener{
        try {
            val rm: String = noRM.getText().toString()
            val name: String = nama.getText().toString()
            val address: String = alamat.getText().toString()
            val phoneNum: String = noHp.getText().toString()
            if (rm != null && rm !== "" || name != null && name !== "" || address != null && address !== "" || phoneNum != null && phoneNum !== "") {
                val i = Intent(this@Pendaftaran, Output::class.java)
                i.putExtra(KEY_RM, rm)
                i.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name)
                i.putExtra(KEY_ALAMAT, address)
                i.putExtra(KEY_HP, noHp)
                startActivity(i)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(application, "Tidak Boleh Kosong Lhoooo...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(application, "ERROR, TRY AGAIN !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
    }


    val resetButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
    resetButton.setOnClickListener{
        noRM.setText("")
        nama.text.clear()
        alamat.text.clear()
        noHp.setText("")
    }
    }
}
```

And this is for the second activity

```
package com.example.praktikumppb

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class Output : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var rm: String? = null
    private val KEY_RM = "RM"

    private var nama: String? = null
    private val KEY_NAME = "NAMA"

    private var address: String? = null
    private val KEY_ALAMAT = "ALAMAT"

    private var phoneNum: String? = null
    private val KEY_HP = "HP"


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_output)

        val txtRM = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView13)
        val txtNama = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView14)
        val txtAddress = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView15)
        val txtPhoneNum = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView16)

        val extras = intent.extras
        rm = extras!!.getString(KEY_RM)
        nama = extras!!.getString(KEY_NAME)
        address = extras!!.getString(KEY_ALAMAT)
        phoneNum = extras!!.getString(KEY_HP)

        txtRM.setText(": $rm ")
        txtNama.setText(": $nama ")
        txtAddress.setText(": $address ")
        txtPhoneNum.setText(": $phoneNum ")
    }
}
```

And this the error alert

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: ...

I'm sorry if my English is bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `EditText` in the phone intent instead of `String`. Fix it like this:

```
i.putExtra(KEY_HP, phoneNum)
```

instead of:

```
i.putExtra(KEY_HP, noHp)
```

Comment: @FebryanAkhdani glad it worked for you, kindly accept the answer ;)